# Where in the C++11 standard does it prohibit 'template <typename T> class A {...}; template <typename T> class A<int> {...};' (if anywhere)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

I am attempting to more fully grasp template syntax and semantics by imagining arcane constructs.  I believe that the following syntax is not allowed by the C++11 standard:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{...};

// phony "specialization"
template <typename T>
class A<int>
{...};
```

However, I cannot find in the C++11 standard where this syntax is disallowed.

Am I correct that the syntax shown is disallowed by the C++11 standard?  If so, where can it be found that the syntax is disallowed?

Comment: This is the error you get with clang++: "error: partial specialization of 'A' does not use any of its template parameters". So I guess you have to search the section on partial specialization, related to the usage of its template parameters. PS: g++ just says "error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:"

Comment: @vsoftco Suppose you have `template <typename T> class A<int> { T t; };`

Comment: @Yakk maybe the answer is that it's due to the fact that it's logically impossible for the construct to make sense that it's disallowed, or that the fact that it's not described anywhere as an *allowed* construct that makes it disallowed, rather than that it is specifically disallowed anywhere.

Comment: Dan, I'm just reading 14.5.5, there should be something there about it. In the example the list on the right matches the initial one in `template<typename T>`, e.g. `template <typename T1>class Foo<T1*>{...};`, which is the specialization for pointers.

Comment: @Dan, it would be insane if the standard had to list all the possible scenarios that should be disallowed. The parameter has to be used in the specialization itself as you need to specialize your template using that parameter. Just `T t;` is not sufficient.

Comment: @RomanL ... perhaps the construct in the question is not disallowed; perhaps it's just that the "phony specialization" can never be instantiated.

Comment: @Dan, specialization is supposed to be specializing to a subset of the parameter space with respect to the initial template. Your initial parameter space is `<T>`. You can specialize to `<int>` which is a valid subset of `<T>` which is done as `template<> class A<int> {};` and is perfectly valid. You could specialize to e.g. a subset of pointers-to-something as per @vsoftco's `template <typename T1>class Foo<T1*> {};`. Your example doesn't make sense because your template parameter is not used to define a subset.

Comment: @RomanL Agreed that the example in the question doesn't make sense.  I am curious as to whether it is specifically disallowed, or even disallowed at all.

Comment: @Dan: I am not sure that asking this question is constructive. If it does not make sense, you don't need to allow or disallow it. The goal of the standard is to have consistent behavior of *sensible code* between compiler implementations, not to avoid nonsense constructs.

Comment: @RomanL I find it constructive.  These comments (such as yours) illuminate to me the nature of rigor in the C++ standard, which I find helpful in reading the standard generally.

Comment: @Dan The way I see it, the standard has to be rigorous when different interpretations are possible leading to inconsistent implementations. In your case 0 interpretations are possible, so all implementations are implicitly consistent ;)

Comment: Yes, but what does it mean?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer Since, I believe, according to the specifications it's either disallowed or will never be instantiated, then it's either meaningless or not well defined.  But I could imagine a possible meaning (not a C++ meaning, but something that feels to me fairly consistent with C++) (see the following comment):

Comment: (Continued from previous comment): Consider `A<int><double>` (not valid C++) The `A<int>` part of this invalid syntax could "match" (in quotes) the primary template, so the compiler searches for any specializations; there is a match on the (phony) `A<int>` specialization, so the compiler tries to use that; this specialization requires a new template parameter, which in this case is a `double`.  (Conceivably the syntax in this comment, in conjunction with the syntax in the question, could be allowed in C++.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite surprised that there is no explicit statement in 14.5.5 [temp.class.spec] saying that all template parameters of a class template partial specialization must be used in the template-argument-list. That would make `template<class T> class A<int>` invalid because `T` is not used in the template-argument-list `<int>`.

I think your phony specialization is only implicitly invalid due to the fact that you can never match it, so it can never be used. If you instantiate `A<int>` then that matches the primary template. It can't match your specialization, because that has an additional template parameter, `T`, which cannot be deduced (you suggest it could be provided by saying `A<int><double>` but that is not valid C++ syntax, so doesn't help).

I've asked the standards committee for clarification why your phony specialization is invalid (obviously it is, but I can't see where it says so).