# Why can't new template parameters be introduced in full specializations?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

In [Where in the C++11 standard does it prohibit 'template <typename T> class A {...}; template <typename T> class A<int> {...};' (if anywhere)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497027/where-in-the-c11-standard-does-it-prohibit-template-typename-t-class-a), it's been confirmed that the following syntax is disallowed in the C++11 standard:

```
/* invalid C++ */

template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    T t;
};

// phony "full specialization" that mistakenly attempts
// to introduce a *new* template parameter
template <typename T>
class A<int>
{
    public:
    int i;
    T t;
};
```

With full understanding that the above syntax does not represent valid C++, I nonetheless could imagine a syntactically unambiguous use of the above code snippet, as follows:

```
A<float> a1;
A<int><double> a2;

a1.t = 2.0f;
a2.i = 2;
a2.t = 2.0;
```

It would seem syntactically and semantically unambiguous for C++ to support the syntax above.

(If the intended semantics is not clear to anybody, please post a comment and I will explain.)

I would describe this syntax as "introducing a new template parameter in a full specialization".

In this imagined scenario of a C++ compiler modified to support the above syntax and semantics, the compiler would see `A<int> a2;` and recognize that the attempted instantiation matches the primary template; it would then search for specializations and find and select the full specialization `A<int>` (ignoring the `<double>`); it would then note that this full specialization introduces a new template parameter `T` which in the case of the declared variable `a2` is a `double`.

If I'm right that the above syntax and semantics is unambiguous, then I'd like to know why this is not part of C++.  I can think of three reasons, but perhaps the answer is different or more complicated.

- There are (almost) no real-world scenarios where this would be useful
- It's too complex for current compilers to be asked to support
- There are too many potential conflicts with other language features that would necessitate many new rules
- Actually, a fourth possibility - the above syntax and semantics would be useful in some real-world scenarios and *could* be reasonably included in the standard, but it's just not part of the current standard.

I'd like to know why this isn't supported in C++ - am I correct that one of my bullet points provides the answer?

Comment: Using a special syntax like `A<int><double>` would thoroughly defeat the point of specialization. Just make a new class named `B` with two template parameters, and use it as `B<int, double>`. The whole point of specialization is that the client doesn't need to do anything special or even know it exists - it just uses the syntax of the primary template, and the specialization automatically kicks in as necessary.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I like that answer.  Could you post it as an answer for consideration?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I could see one scenario where there would be a difference in behavior with the syntax in my question.  If you leave the class name as `A` and use `A<int><double>` (rather than introducing a new class, `B`), then you could automatically disable (via compiler errors) *all* the `A` specializations of the form `A<T1><T2>` simply by commenting out the primary template for `A`.  Also, by using `A` it would be clear that you mean the same thing semantically in some sense everywhere you use `A`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. It doesn't make sense to have a specialization without a primary template - what exactly would the specialization be a special case of? If you comment out the primary template, and that somehow disables `A<T1><T2>` specializations in that hypothetical world of yours, then what's left? Is there something named `A` that still could somehow be used?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik As I mentioned, by commenting out the primary template for `A`, it would result in compiler errors everywhere `A` appears.  I could see this, theoretically, as being useful during development as a rapid way to isolate all usages of `A`.

Comment: Comment out `B`, too - that would result in compiler errors everywhere `B` appears. I still don't see the point of that weird syntax you are inventing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ... What if you had 20 different specializations?  It would then be easier to comment out just one definition, rather than 21.

Comment: Enclose their definitions in an `#ifdef`. You propose a solution in desperate search of a non-existent problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That works, but it adds ugly lines of code.

Comment: No uglier than `A<int><double>`. Besides, you are adding those ugly lines of code to make the program fail to compile. An actual valid program would be nice and pretty.

Comment: I don't agree.  I think `A<int><double> a;` is cleaner than `#ifdef USE_A B<int, double> b; #endif`.

Comment: If you say so. Please feel free to design a programming language that has this syntax, or propose it to the C++ committee for standardization.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If I encounter a realistic use-case where I think this would be useful, I may.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I make your point in my answer, along with an example of how to achieve the same result in standard C++.

Comment: You are not specializing a class template, you are specializing a (hypothetical) class template template. (Now imagine template template template parameters of class template templates.)

Answer (score 5):

Oooh, this explodes in funny ways.

For clarity, I assume you mean that with your example code,

```
 A<double> a; // okay
 A<int> a2;   // not okay, A<int> is not a class but a class template.
```

Now let's try to use that in other templates. Consider

```
template<typename T>
void function<A<T> const &a) { ... }

A<double> a;
A<int><double> a2;

function(a);  // that looks okay.
function(a2); // er...compiler error, I guess?
```

That's not too bad yet; the compiler could just complain about that. I think we're beginning to see how this is a bit strange, though. Well, take it up a notch:

```
template<template<typename> class A> struct Foo { ... };

Foo<A> f; // this would usually work, does it now?
```

If you answer no, what if the specialisation is not known at the point of compilation?

**EDIT:** Expanding this a bit, consider a real-world scenario for template-template arguments that I like to call pack traits:

```
template<template<typename> class, typename...> struct applies_to_all;

template<template<typename> class predicate, typename T, typename... Pack>
struct applies_to_all<predicate, T, Pack...> {
  static bool const value =
    predicate<T>::value && applies_to_all<predicate, Pack...>::value;
};

template<template<typename> class predicate>
struct applies_to_all<predicate> {
  static bool const value = true;
};

...

bool b = applies_to_all<std::is_integral, int, long, double>::value;
```

And feed this something like `A` that's a class for everything but `int` and a class template for `int`. Then try to work out

```
applies_to_all<A, double, float, std::string, int>::value
```

And note that this simple case is not the code you're likely to see. What you really get is this stuff nested three levels deep in other templates, where it looks like this:

```
applies_to_all<A, T...>::value
```

Possibly a behavior could be defined for this that is mathematically consistent, but I doubt that one could be defined that is useful. Certainly it's not POLA-compliant.

There's probably a lot more you could come up with along these lines. Blurring the lines between classes and class templates in this fashion is bound to break all sorts of stuff.

Comment: Thanks!  For the first example, I agree that would be a compiler error.  In the second example, I think this could work - the only template arguments to `A` that would be allowed in the definition of `Foo` would be ones that use the primary template, because the primary template requires 1 template argument "group" (matching the declaration of `Foo`), not two.  If you wanted the (new form of) specialization with two template parameter "groups", you could write `template<template<typename><typename> class A> struct Foo { ... };`.`

Comment: I'll expand a bit on it, I think. In short, it cannot really work if Foo does not know a lot about its parameter, and that's the usual case for templates.

Comment: Great example of a more complex scenario! Still, to me it seems that this just boils down to the second example you gave: Because the primary template for `applies_to_all` defines its first template parameter as a template taking one template argument, that requirement will cascade through the whole way and so the value `applies_to_all<A, double, float, std::string, int>::value` will always utilize the primary template for `A`, even for `int`'s. So, I do not think this is a fundamentally more complex scenario logically or mathematically (any more than typical long chains of template verbiage).

Answer (score 3):

A name in C++ represents one kind of entity, and this kind is known by the first name lookup.

The name `A` in your example is a class template name. Thus it follows that `A<T>` for any `T` is a class name.

This is a useful property for a language to have. Breaking this property means the language gets a major bump in complexity (for both compiler and user).

So even if you could find all the edge cases and fix the issues Wintermute has pointed out, it would still be most likely be rejected, because it makes the language more irregular, more surprising, less uniform. C++ is already burdened by quite a bit of irregularity; it doesn't make sense to add more.

I would encourage you to post your intended use case, and we can probably show you a better way.

Comment: Thanks!  Believe it or not, I don't have an intended use case.  Clarifying this just helps me read through discussions and specification documents more quickly, because I can quickly lay out all *theoretical* syntax possibilities in my mind and clearly reject non-sensical ones, just so long as I understand why they're non-sensical.

Answer (score 1):

Template resolution is always against the primary template.

Any additional template parameters introduced in a specialization, would just be hanging in thin air, with nothing to connect them to any template usage.

Comment: That's true according to the rules of C++, which is why the syntax in my question is invalid.  However, if the rules of C++ were expanded to allow the syntax in my question, then the additional template parameters would no longer be hanging in thin air, unless I'm mistaken that the syntax in my question is unambiguous.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: oh, sorry for only reading the top of the question. hm. well one reason i see is that it would complicate things and make standard even larger. at present it would take a lot of effort to introduce this: writing a proposal, arguing for the benefits, getting someone to champion it in committee. and possibly through that process you'd discover one or more reasons why not good idea (or perhaps you'd discover that it's even better idea than thought).

Answer (score 1):

One of the core semantics of templates in C++ is that a template-id has a single template-argument-list: `A<int>`. Your proposed change allows a template-id to have more than one template-argument-list: `A<int><double>`.

You can achieve the desired result in standard C++ using template default-arguments:

```
template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct A
{
    T t;
};

template <typename U>
struct A<int, U>
{
    int i;
    T t;
};

A<float> a1;
A<int, double> a2;

a1.t = 2.0f;
a2.i = 2;
a2.t = 2.0;
```

The syntax `A<int, double>` is simpler than `A<int><double>` - a single argument list rather than multiple argument lists - which is the main reason why I wouldn't make your proposed change.

Having said that, it would be possible to relax the requirement that all explicit/partial specializations of a template take the same number of template arguments. Instead, it could be required that a specialization takes as least as many template arguments as the primary template. If that was the case, you could omit the redundant second parameter in the primary template.

```
template <typename T>
struct A; // primary template, definition omitted for brevity

template <typename U>
struct A<int, U>; // partial specialization, definition omitted for brevity

A<float> a1; // OK, selects primary template
A<int, double> a2; // OK, selects partial specialization
A<float, float> a3; // Error, no valid specialization
```

I don't think this change would break anything. The next question is whether it would improve anything?

Comment: Thanks!  Note that this would require changing the primary template to support *all* desired specializations.  The syntax in my question seems cleaner to me because it avoids that requirement.

Comment: You could achieve the same without changing the syntax, just by relaxing the requirement that all specializations take the same number of arguments as the primary template.

Comment: I think you're leaving off the piece where you leave the (additional) template argument's type unspecified (i.e., leave it a `T`) ... could that also work in the way you're describing, do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the edit - it makes sense!  I think this is the same syntax as I used in my question, but including the template parameter as a template argument (i.e., `template <typename U> struct A<int, U>;` rather than `template <typename U> struct A<int>;`).